# where clause in nested isNull query giving unexpected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, isnull

The below query returns around 200000 results.

The working of nested `where` clause in this query is not very clear i.e where is it coming in the picture ?

If I comment out the where clause inside the isNull then I get 0 results, which is fine and expected as the Max(invoiceID) is not null after join.

```
select * from CustomerServices where isNull((
                                SELECT MAX(invoiceid) 
                                FROM Invoices 
                                    LEFT JOIN InvoicesHistory
                                        ON InvoicesHistory.ServiceHistoryID = Invoices.ServiceHistoryID 
                                WHERE serviceID = Invoices.serviceID
                            ),0)=0
```

Please let me know if you want me to add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `not exists`:

```
select cs.*
from CustomerServices cs
where not exists (select 1
                  from Invoices i left join
                       InvoicesHistory ih
                       on ih.ServiceHistoryID = i.ServiceHistoryID 
                  where cs.serviceID = i.serviceID
                 );
```

In your case, the nested `WHERE` clause is not doing anything.  It is equivalent to:

```
Invoices.serviceID = Invoices.serviceID
```

by the scoping rules in SQL.  In all likelihood, this is intended to be a correlation clause and hence needs a qualified column name.

Comment: There is no need for " max(i.invoiceid)" is a WHERE EXISTS. Based on the table names, it also looks like the LEFT JOIN to InvoicesHistory is unnessary.

Comment: @JasonA.Long . . . Au contraire.  `max(i.invoiceid)` is precisely incorrect.  It forces the subquery to return exactly one row (this is fixed).  The `left join` is in the OP's original question, so I have no idea if it is needed or not.  I will note that the name of the `join` column is rather unexpected.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: After understanding the complete use case, I have found that they were actually trying to implement the 'not exists', which you have mentioned in here.